# JAVA toLowerCase() is getting symbols

Tags: java

I got a problem with this symbol — (not -). When I use `tolowercase()` function, it shows ���. I don't know how to fix this. Please help. Thank you.

```
public String content = "noise—tap, tap—plash, plash—as"; 
this.content = this.content.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(this.content);
```

Output: noise���tap, tap���plash, plash���as

Comment: What are you editing your source code with?

Comment: works fine for me...Using eclipse.

Comment: Check the encoding of your editor vs the encoding used by java

Comment: I use nano. I change the environment of JVM by `export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. Now, it's worked. But now I get the new problem which is `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. How can I suppress this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output in your case depends on three things.

1. The charachter set of the source code (BTW. in my humble opinion you should use UTF-8)
2. The lowercase replacement of the — character (on my system, this is the '–' character, but your mileage may vary, there are some broken unicode implementations on this planet)
3. The predefined character set of your console (On my Linux box, this is also UTF-8, but e.g. many windows boxes or other legacy systems may define other character sets. If the '–' character is not available in this set, you'll get the replacement characters in your output.#

Edit: I'd guess that 3. is the most likely culprit. You can look at the system property `file.encoding` for confirmation.